# boolean allLess(int[] one,int[] two) method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, boolean

so I am trying to make this method that takes in two int Arrays and returns true if each element in the first array is less than the element at the same index in the second array if the arrays are of different lengths then it will compare up to the length of the shorter array. this is what i have so far but i keep failing two j unit tests and cant figure out what is causing it. Thank you for any help in advance.

here are the two junit tests i am failing

```
    @Test
public void testSecondLessFirstLonger() {
    int[]   one    = { 5, 5, 5 };
    int[]   two    = { 4 };
    boolean actual = Program1.allLess( one, two );
    assertFalse( "Incorrect result",actual );
}
@Test
public void testSecondLessSecondLonger() {
    int[]   one    = { 2 };
    int[]   two    = { 1, 0 };
    boolean actual = Program1.allLess( one, two );
    assertFalse( "Incorrect result",actual );
}

import java.util.Arrays;
```

here is the code i have so far

```
public class Program1 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[]   one    = { 2 };
        int[]   two    = { 1, 0 };
        System.out.println(allLess(one, two));
    }
    public static boolean allLess(int[] one,int[] two)
    {
        if (one.length != two.length) 
        {
            int len = 0;
            if(one.length <= two.length)
            {
                len = one.length;
            }
            if(two.length < one.length)
            {
                len = two.length;
            }
            boolean[] boo = new boolean[len];
            for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                if(one[i] < two[i])
                {
                    boo[i] = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    boo[i] = false;
                }       
            }
            if(Arrays.asList(boo).contains(false))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < one.length; i++)
    {
        if (one[i] >= two[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint - think about a way to use the simple for loop in the case with different size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you could try something like this:

```
public static boolean allLess(final int[] array1, final int[] array2){
    for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(array1.length, array2.length); i++)
        if(array1[i] >= array2[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'd say `Math.min()` would be more readable in the condition.

Comment: thank you, my code was so in-optimal compared to this. forgot about Math.min to.

Answer (score 0):

//this way works too. did you get program 3 done yet? Its giving me issues

```
import java.lang.Math.*;

public class Program1 {
public static boolean allLess(int[] one, int[] two) {

    if (one == null || two == null) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(one.length, two.length); i++) {

        if (two[i] <= one[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

}

Comment: How is that any different from Josh's solution?  The important lines are all the same.